# What adhesive do I use to mount a glass pane in shed?

Tags: windows, shed, glass

I’m replacing a shattered pane of glass in my shed. When removing the pane I noticed it was held in with some adhesive, in addition to the plastic that was pushing the pane up against an aluminum frame.

I’m just wondering what kind of tape or sealant I’m supposed to use when putting the new pane in.

Here’s a picture of what was on the original glass.

[image]

Comment: It might help to include a picture of the frame it mounts into, as well. _Usually_ windows aren't held in place by a strip of tape, so there's something a bit unusual going on here and we'd need to see more.

Comment: Normally windows are glazed. Adhesives or tape implies it was cob-jobbed.

Comment: aluminium windows all work differently

Answer (score 1):

In the olden days (read: until a few decades ago), most windows were built and repaired with glazing putty. It's basically rolled in the palms until warm and in a rope, then pressed against the glass-frame joint with a putty knife or other flat tool. You'd use a smaller bead between the back of the glass and the frame, too, as a seal.

The outcome is ideally something like this, which seals against airflow and sheds water:

[image]

[More on that](https://www.finehomebuilding.com/2018/01/11/how-to-glaze-a-wood-window)

Nowadays (inasmuch as we re-glaze anything in the first place), you can use glazing tape. It's quicker, less messy, and maybe more suitable for beginners. If you use glazing tape you may still want to run a bead of silicone around the outside to lock things together more robustly.

[image]